# What does ~ mean inside the brackets of a function call in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

For example, I have a function

```
[power, capacity] = function_name(users, distance, radius)
```

and the function call is

```
[~, capacity] = function_name(users, distance, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ just means that you don't want to store the result in any variable.

here is a detailed explanation:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/72537-what-does-a-tilde-inside-square-brackets-mean

And the most relevant section: "when you use [~,palette], that means that you just want the second output of your function, and do not care the first one."

Comment: Thank you! Google search does not accept the "~" sign, it simply ignores it - do you believe that? And I don't know the English word for that symbol, so I could not find a way to "google" it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help!  Please accept the answer as well :)  For your info, it is called a "tilde" in english.

Comment: Yes, I will, I just I have to wait for 7 minutes to do so. Thanks also for the vocabulary info!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that restriction!  Good to know.